# GObject disconnect handler

Tags: python, gobject

I connect a callback handler `on_fader_finished` to my  `GObject` fader:

```
fader.connect("animation-finished", self.on_fader_finished)
```

Now, I want that the callback handler disconnects itself after having been called.

```
def on_fader_finished(self, fader):
    fader.disconnect(???)
```

Unfortunately, the `disconnect` functions needs the handler id to be passed as argument.

I could of course try to save the handler id somehow when connecting the callback handler and later retrieve it, but that's pretty complicated in my case, because the same handler function may be connected to multiple GObjects dynamically.

It would be much easier if the callback could simply disconnect itself from the GObject.
As my GObjects usually only have one callback handler, disconnecting all would also be a fine solution.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`GObject.signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handlers-disconnect-by-func). Something like:

```
fader.signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func(self.on_fader_finished)
```

Comment: That call doesn't exist in PyGObject afaik

Comment: How about `fader.disconnect_by_func(self.on_fader_finished)`?